# In Angular 8, can routerLinkActive jump-to?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm looking to implement a footer where the navigation if `routerLinkActive` jumps to the top. I understand that I could add a top of page component, but I'm looking for the footer links to behave this way.

What I do have implemented at the moment is a shared service that will do a smooth scroll to the top on a route change. I'm hoping there is a way this can be accomplished by manipulating the `routerLinkActive`

Note: I'm using Bootstrap 4

```html
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-md-0 mb-3 footerlinksholder">
          <!-- Links -->
          <ul class="footerlinks">
            <li id="pageLinks">
              <a [routerLink]= "'/'" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active-route']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pageLinks">
              <a [routerLink]= "'/solution'" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active-route']">Solutions</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pageLinks">
              <a [routerLink]= "'/about'" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active-route']">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="careerLink">
              <a [routerLink]= "'/careers'" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active-route']">Careers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```